# Get comments of Instagram photo

Tags: java, android, json, instagram

I'm trying to get comments from Instagram photos. It works, except it prints only the first 8 comments. I based my code off of http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-instagram1/index.html, so in theory it should work (there's was done in PHP). There's probably a stupid mistake in mine somewhere, so if somebody could point it out I would appreciate it bunches <3.

```
// Construct url to get Instagram feed
mAccessToken = sharedPref.getString(API_ACCESS_TOKEN, null);
// todo: we have to switch to -1, right? 
String feed  = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/feed?access_token="+mAccessToken;

// Making a request to url and getting response
String json = sh.makeServiceCall(feed, ServiceHandler.GET);

// do the stuff 
if (json != null) {
    try {
        // make a new json object
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json);                  

        // data 
        data = obj.getJSONArray(TAG_DATA);

        // looping through the data
        for (int i=0; i < data.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject c = (JSONObject)data.get(i);
            JSONObject img = c.getJSONObject(TAG_IMAGES);
            JSONObject thum = img.getJSONObject(TAG_LOW_RESOLUTION);
            JSONObject comments = c.getJSONObject(TAG_COMMENTS);
            JSONObject user = c.getJSONObject(TAG_USER);
            JSONObject likes = c.getJSONObject(TAG_LIKES);

            String likes_count = likes.getString(TAG_LIKES_COUNT);
            String profile_picture = user.getString(TAG_PROFILE_PICTURE);
            String username = user.getString(TAG_USERNAME);
            String comments_count = comments.getString(TAG_COMMENTS_COUNT);

            System.out.println(comments_count);         
            String urlOfPic = thum.getString(TAG_URL);               
            JSONArray comments_data = comments.getJSONArray("data");

            for (int z=0; z < comments_data.length(); z++) {
                String commentText = ((JSONObject) comments_data.get(z)).getString("text").toString();
                System.out.println("commentText ==" +commentText);  
                long created_time = Long.parseLong((((JSONObject) comments_data.get(z)).getString("created_time")).toString());
                Date date = new Date(created_time * 1000);
                System.out.println(date);
            }                           
            System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------------------");
                                                           HashMap<String, String> photos = new HashMap<String, String>();  

            photos.put("likes.count", likes_count);

            photos.put(TAG_PROFILE_PICTURE, profile_picture);
            photos.put(TAG_USERNAME, username);
            photos.put(TAG_URL, urlOfPic);
            photos.put(TAG_COMMENTS_COUNT, comments_count);

            instagram_list.add(photos);
        }                   
    } catch (JSONException ex) { 
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to be sure: have you verified the JSON document actually contains more than 8?

Comment: @SamJones Yes, I have. One of the comments includes 417, but only prints 8.